# Working with deep lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, searching

I want to store parameters value such that the function that depends on those parameters.

For example, let's say I have a function that depends on three arguments: f(x;a,b), where a and b are parameters. I want to calculate the value of the function for ranges of x, a and b. Just to avoid confusions, let's say x is in the interval [1,10], a is in the interval [-10,-1] and b is in the interval [1,10]:

```
f[a_, b_, x_] := a*x^2 + b*x;
fimage = Outer[
  f, {Range[-10, -1, 1]}, {Range[1, 10, 1]}, {Range[1, 10, 1]}]
```

Is there any good practice to store the values of the parameters such that the function is positive? I want to run in the deep fimage object, search for fimage>=0 and store a and b. Ultimately what I want to have is a CountourPlot of f that indicates for which combinations of a and b f is positive.

Apologies if my problem is not clear. Please let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is no particular reason for using `Outer`, then this is simple and straightforward:

```
tab = Flatten[Table[{a, b, x, f[a, b, x]}, {a, -10, -1}, {b, 1, 10}, {x, 1, 10}], 2];

pos = Select[tab, #[[4]] > 0 &]
```

Part (because `Length @ pos = 100`) of the output:

> {{-9, 10, 1, 1}, {-8, 9, 1, 1}, {-8, 10, 1, 2}, {-7, 8, 1, 1}, {-7, 9,
>      1, 2},...}

Comment: Of course. Thank you for clarifying this. I will give it a try in my "real" problem.

Answer (score 7):

corey979's answer is simple and elegant for small numbers of values of `x`, `a`, and `b`.  But if you are using a large number of such values, you may bump up against memory constraints from storing all such values in memory and only then selecting the positive ones.  A more memory- and time-efficient method might use the `Nothing` command, dropping the negative values as they are calculated:

```
table = Flatten[Table[If[f[a, b, x] > 0, {a, b, x, f[a, b, x]}, Nothing], 
                                   {a, -10, -1}, {b, 1, 10}, {x, 1, 10}], 2]
```

This gives the same results.

Note, however, that if your "real" function `f` is computationally time-intensive, this method may slow you down since it calculates the non-negative values twice.  In such instances, corey979's method will likely work better.

Comment: You could use a `With` block to avoid computing `f` twice.

Comment: Good point. I did't know about Nothing. Thank you!

Comment: You could use an anonymous function to avoid computing `f` twice, i.e. `If[#>0,{a,b,x,#},Nothing]&@f[a,b,c]`

Answer (score 6):

I think I would use `Reap`, `Sow` and `Do` for this problem. With these functions you can get the pairs `{a, b}` where `f > 0` in one pass through the data

```
f[a_, b_, x_] := a*x^2 + b*x
Reap[Do[If[f[a, b, x] > 0, Sow[{a, b}]], {a, -10, -1}, {b, 1, 10}, {x, 1, 10}]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{-9, 10}, {-8, 9}, {-8, 10}, {-7, 8}, {-7, 9}, {-7, 10}, {-6, 7}, {-6, 8}, 
>  {-6, 9}, {-6, 10}, {-5, 6}, {-5, 7}, {-5, 8}, {-5, 9}, {-5, 10}, {-4, 5}, 
>  {-4, 6}, {-4, 7}, {-4, 8}, {-4, 9}, {-4, 9}, {-4, 10}, {-4, 10}, {-3, 4}, 
>  {-3, 5}, {-3, 6}, {-3, 7}, {-3, 7}, {-3, 8}, {-3, 8}, {-3, 9}, {-3, 9}, 
>  {-3, 10}, {-3, 10}, {-3, 10}, {-2, 3}, {-2, 4}, {-2, 5}, {-2, 5}, {-2, 6}, 
>  {-2, 6}, {-2, 7}, {-2, 7}, {-2, 7}, {-2, 8}, {-2, 8}, {-2, 8}, {-2, 9}, 
>  {-2, 9}, {-2, 9}, {-2, 9}, {-2, 10}, {-2, 10}, {-2, 10}, {-2, 10}, {-1, 2}, 
>  {-1, 3}, {-1, 3}, {-1, 4}, {-1, 4}, {-1, 4}, {-1, 5}, {-1, 5}, {-1, 5}, 
>  {-1, 5}, {-1, 6}, {-1, 6}, {-1, 6}, {-1, 6}, {-1, 6}, {-1, 7}, {-1, 7}, 
>  {-1, 7}, {-1, 7}, {-1, 7}, {-1, 7}, {-1, 8}, {-1, 8}, {-1, 8}, {-1, 8}, 
>  {-1, 8}, {-1, 8}, {-1, 8}, {-1, 9}, {-1, 9}, {-1, 9}, {-1, 9}, {-1, 9}, 
>  {-1, 9}, {-1, 9}, {-1, 9}, {-1, 10}, {-1, 10}, {-1, 10}, {-1, 10}, {-1, 10}, 
>  {-1, 10}, {-1, 10}, {-1, 10}, {-1, 10}}
> ```

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. I will also give it a try in my true problem and I will come back to all the answers again. Thank you very much!